# How to log output in cypress cucumber html report?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` for my automation. I am looking for how to print output/log in html report. In Cucumber-Java I have `scenario.write("hello");` statement to print messages in cucumber html report. Likewise how can i print in Cypress-Cucumber report?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found an answer and it works, but let me know if there is any other option.

```
attach("hello world");
```

Comment: How are you using attach in the code? Could you please share some doc links or code snippets for reference?

Comment: Refer this, as it is straight forward usage. `Then(\`I can see the variable sharing\`, function () {
  attach(\`The sample is ${sample}\`);
  attach(\`The global error message after is ${global.errorMsg}\`);
});
`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
cy.log("hello")
```